# How does this printing code work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I found this code somewhere. It prints "abcd" to the screen but in a weird way. I would like someone to tell me how it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class X
{
    typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> Iter;
    Iter it;
public:
    X(std::streambuf* p) : it(p) { }

    Iter begin()
        { return it; }
    Iter end()
        { return Iter(); }
};

void printbuf(X x, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> it)
{
    for (auto c : x)
    {
        *it = c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::stringbuf buf("abcd", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    printbuf(&buf, std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Can you link to where you found it?

Comment: @Borgleader  Sorry, it wasn't linked on so

Comment: The part of this you probably find most confusing is the implicit construction of *both* parameters passed to `printbuf()`. An `X` is implicitly constructed from the `stringbuf` address, and a `std::ostreambuf_iterator<>` is likewise implicitly constructed from `std::cout`. Get past that and it becomes much simpler to comprehend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a class `X` which encapsulates an `istreambuf_iterator<char>`. This is an iterator type which allows us to treat a stream buffer as an iterator range for standard algorithms.

```
class X
{
    typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> Iter;
    Iter it;
public:
```

The class is constructible from a pointer to a stream buffer instance.

```
    X(std::streambuf* p) : it(p) { }
```

It exposes `begin()` and `end()` member functions to allow it to be used with the range-based `for` loop.

```
    Iter begin()
        { return it; }
    Iter end()
        { return Iter(); }
};
```

`printbuf()` is a function which accepts an instance of our range class `X`, as well as an `ostreambuf_iterator<char>`, which—you guessed it—allows us to use an output stream buffer as an *output iterator*.

```
void printbuf(X x, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> it)
{
```

So we iterate over every character in the input range.

```
    for (auto c : x)
    {
```

If you haven’t dealt with output iterators before, you can think of them as an object resembling a pointer, to which you *write* values using dereference and assignment. [`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) is a commonly used output iterator, for building containers—you usually construct it using [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). But I digress.

We copy each character to the output iterator.

```
        *it = c;
    }
}

int main()
{
```

Here we construct a string buffer, which is both an input and output stream buffer. We only use the input capability in this example.

```
    std::stringbuf buf("abcd", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
```

Now we use an implicitly-constructed `X` instance to treat the string buffer as an iterator range. Then we copy that range to an output stream buffer iterator—also implicitly constructed—to `std::cout`.

```
    printbuf(&buf, std::cout);
}
```

The effect is that we’re looping over each character in the buffer and copying it to standard output.

Answer (score 2):

```
printbuf(&buf, std::cout);
```

Passing `std::stringbuf*` as the first paramter causes an implicit construction of `X` to match `printbuf()`

And also for the second parameter, an implicit
contruction occurs, an instance of `std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>` is created from `std::cout` (std::ostream)

```
void printbuf(X x, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> it)
{
    for (auto c : x)
    {
        *it = c;
    }
}
```

In printbuf, the foreach loop (range based for loop) uses `X::begin()` and `X::end()` to loop over all characters in that wrapped `std::stringbuf` and writes them to `std::cout` via the `std::ostreambuf_iterator` (`it`)